# Rotate single object placed in geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have added an object using an "object info" node that's going through a "set position" node – I want to rotate this object around the main objects axis. Is there any way I can do this without making it go through a "Distribute Points to Faces" or "Instance on Points" (as I only want one instance of it)?

I know I can do this in an easier way but...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a transform node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to rotate the original geometry and relocate it at the same time, you can use the transform node on the original geometry:

[image: Showing a simple use of the transform node]

If you want to bring another object into the geometry, as you do, you can do exactly the same thing:

[image: Showing an Object Info geometry being transformed by rotation]

As you surmised, *Rotate Instances* is only for instantiated geometry.

Comment: Oooooh this is exactly what I needed. I can't imagine I never tried to search for "transform". Makes so much sense now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the search for "rotate" in the add menu you can easily discover all the rotation related nodes:

[image]

Rotate Instances seems like the most promising one. When I add it after the object nothing seems to happen, but while doing so I saw this suspicious checkbox "As Instance". Seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Right, I've tried this but it doesn't work. I think it's because it's not technically an instance? Feels like it has to go through another node at the end to make it work. It tells me "Realized data in input geometry is ignored". I have also tried adding a normal and a "Rotate Euler" node both with and without the "rotate instances" node but no dice.

Comment: @BingoBango: Martynas proposal does work. What Blender version r u using? Please provide blend file where you tried that so we can check it.